# How to reuse cypher query results in another query using java

Tags: java, neo4j

I want to use the result of one query again in other queries for optimization. But didn't find right way of doing it.

For example:

Query1:

```
MATCH (a: ABC)
MATCH (d: DEF)
MERGE (a)-[HAS_RELATION]->(b)
RETURN a, b
```

Query 2:

```
MATCH (a: ABC)
MATCH (p: PQR)
MERGE (a)-[HAS_RELATION1]->(p)
RETURN a, p
```

In the above queries, the `MATCH (a: ABC)` is used twice in 2 different queries. So for optimization, I was trying to find a way in which the result of matches will be saved in variables and used directly while merging the relations. These queries are run one after the other in java.

I'm using org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:4.4.2 for neo4j java code.

```
public int addEmployees( final String companyName )
{
    try ( Session session = driver.session() )
    {
        int employees = 0;
        List<Record> persons = session.readTransaction( new TransactionWork<List<Record>>()
        {
            @Override
            public List<Record> execute( Transaction tx )
            {
                return matchPersonNodes( tx );
            }
        } );
        for ( final Record person : persons )
        {
            employees += session.writeTransaction( new TransactionWork<Integer>()
            {
                @Override
                public Integer execute( Transaction tx )
                {
                    tx.run( "MATCH (emp:Person {name: $person_name}) " +
                            "MERGE (com:Company {name: $company_name}) " +
                            "MERGE (emp)-[:WORKS_FOR]->(com)",
                            parameters( "person_name", person.get( "name" ).asString(), "company_name",
                                    companyName ) );
                    return 1;
                }
            } );
        }
        return employees;
    }
}

private static List<Record> matchPersonNodes( Transaction tx )
{
    return tx.run( "MATCH (a:Person) RETURN a.name AS name" ).list();
}
```

I want to do somewhat like this, but with nodes and not their properties.

```
public int addEmployees( final String companyName )
{
    try ( Session session = driver.session() )
    {
        int employees = 0;
        List<Record> persons = session.readTransaction( new TransactionWork<List<Record>>()
        {
            @Override
            public List<Record> execute( Transaction tx )
            {
                return matchPersonNodes( tx );
            }
        } );
        for ( final Record person : persons )
        {
            employees += session.writeTransaction( new TransactionWork<Integer>()
            {
                @Override
                public Integer execute( Transaction tx )
                {
                    tx.run( "WITH {person} as emp" +
                            "MERGE (com:Company {name: $company_name}) " +
                            "MERGE (emp)-[:WORKS_FOR]->(com)",
                            parameters( "person", person, "company_name",
                                    companyName ) );
                    return 1;
                }
            } );
        }
        return employees;
    }
}

private static List<Record> matchPersonNodes( Transaction tx )
{
    return tx.run( "MATCH (a:Person) RETURN p" ).list();
}
```

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at [`WITH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/), seems like what you're looking for

Comment: Yeah, as I already said I would want to do it java way. As the `MATCH (a: ABC)` is used in multiple places in my cypher queries. I know how to use `WITH` with normal cyphers in neo4j. Just that I need help with multiple queries using same match in java.

Comment: Ok, to clarify: you want to leave query 1 and query 2 as they are – so you do not want to write a new, different query using `WITH`. Instead you want to run query 1, then use Java code to take query 1 output and use that for query 2? Something like that? If so, that sounds complicated and error-prone. It's not clear what you would gain with that approach vs. letting the database do it for you (with a single query using `WITH`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this using the `WITH` operator, you can merge the relations in a single query:

```
MATCH (a: ABC)
MATCH (d: DEF)
MERGE (a)-[HAS_RELATION]->(b)
WITH a, b
MATCH (p: PQR)
MERGE (a)-[HAS_RELATION1]->(p)
RETURN a, b, p
```

**UPDATE:**

In terms of performance of these two queries, for `MATCH (a:ABC)`, you don't need to worry about it. In neo4j, labels act as index, for nodes and their lookup is very fast. So `MATCH (a:ABC)`, is basically a sort of index based lookup. Try profiling your query, and you might see a stage named as `NodeByLabelScan`. You can read about execution stages [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/operators/).

However, if you still want to a way to do `MATCH (a:ABC)` once, I can suggest you a approach (not tested). In java, store the outcome of this query

```
MATCH (a: ABC)
MATCH (d: DEF)
MERGE (a)-[HAS_RELATION]->(b)
RETURN a, b
```

specifically, `a` nodes in a list, say `List<ABC> aNodes`.
Try sending this list, as parameter to the other query, and use `UNWIND` there, like this:

```
UNWIND $list AS a
MATCH (d: DEF)
MERGE (a)-[HAS_RELATION]->(b)
RETURN a, b
```

It might work. Try it out.

Comment: Yeah, as I already said I would want to do it java way. As the `MATCH (a: ABC)` is used in multiple places in my cypher queries.

Comment: Updated the answer, it might help.